# How woocommerce product and categories are translate into other language?

Tags: wordpress, internationalization, woocommerce

How I can translate WooCommerce product and categories into other language.
We have the WordPress default function:

```
define(WP_LANG,'');
```

I have set:

```
define (WP_LANG,'heIL');
```

It changes all WordPress content but does not change WooCommerce product name categories.

Comment: This might help.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-multilingual/

Comment: I there any free plugin for this ?